# Proving this algebra fact

Tags: commutative-algebra

The Nullstellensatz for $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ gives a dictionary between radical ideals and varieties, which makes the following assertion obvious: a radical ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is the intersection of the maximal ideals containing it. Is there a simple purely algebraic way of seeing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any radical ideal (in any ring) is an intersection of prime ideals. So the question becomes why a prime ideal is an intersection of maximal ideals. Such rings are called [Jacobson rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring). A field is clearly Jacobson. It is a general fact (a more general form of the Nullstellensatz) that a ring finitely generated over  a Jacobson ring is Jacobson. (This is in Eisenbud ch. 4.) So any affine coordinate ring is Jacobson.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was a really simple way, but it seems not.

Answer (score 2):

There is an elegant abstract approach to the Hilbert Nullstellensatz 
discovered circa 1950 by Goldman, Krull and Zariski. For more 
on this look up the terms: G-domain, Hilbert ring, Jacobson ring, e.g. see Kaplansky's textbook *Commutative Rings*.
See also [D.J. Bernstein's ZGK page](http://cr.yp.to/zgk.html)  which has some online links, 
including expositions of an "elementary" proof by R. Munshi (1999).